# Set variable under specific mode emacs

Tags: emacs, latex

Looking to set a variable under latex mode.  The idea is that the value set under latex mode will override the value of the same variable set in the customise section. I am very new to emacs so these are my attempts:

```
    (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(setq line-move-visual t))
    (add-hook 'latex-mode-hook (lambda () (setq line-move-visual t)))
```

Why do these not work?  What should I do instead?

Clarification: looking to set the variable (setq line-move-visual t) as I have it as (setq line-move-visual nil) for all other files

Comment: The second line should work. How did you set `line-move-visual` to nil for everything else? Those two settings might be interfering.

Comment: Sorry, just realised you already mentioned that in your question. Can't think of a reason the second line wouldn't work, then...

Comment: If you are using the AUCTeX library instead of the built-in `tex-mode.el`, then how about trying?:   `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (setq line-move-visual t)))`  Everyone who uses AUCTeX gets confused (at the outset) regarding the hooks because they are so similar to the built-in library:  https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Modes-and-Hooks.html

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for help everyone, yes you are right, I am using auctex and did not know that a different hook was to be used. I can test this later today.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you just `setq` the variable in your LaTeX-mode-hook it will also have an effect on any other open buffer.  It is possible to make the change only effect the current buffer:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (make-local-variable 'line-move-visual)
        (setq line-move-visual nil)))
```

Also, please note that the hook for the default mode for LaTeX in Emacs is called `latex-mode-hook` but the hook when you are using the (far superior) AUCTeX is called `LaTeX-mode-hook`

EDIT: Changed `make-variable-buffer-local` to `make-local-variable`. See comments to this answer.

Comment: I think you want `make-local-variable` instead of `make-variable-buffer-local`, which [affects the behavior of the variable in all buffers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html#index-make_002dvariable_002dbuffer_002dlocal-823).

Comment: Hm, I think, you're right, @VasiliyFaronov. This way worked for me for decades, but probably more because of sparse use than because of correctness. Edited the answer.

Comment: Since Emacs 24.3 you can use `setq-local` in place of the sequence of `make-local-variable` and `setq`